# ModuleNotFoundError after installing that particular module

Tags: pip, package, ckeditor, python-3.7

I'm currently setting up a developer environment and I want to use the package `django-ckeditor`. So, I executed `pip3 install django-ckeditor` which yielded

```
Installing collected packages: django-ckeditor
Successfully installed django-ckeditor-5.8.0
```

in my terminal. After starting Django, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'`. So, I checked the following things:

- I am using python3(.7) to start Django so I am using the packages from pip3(.7).
- `ls -l .local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ | grep "ckeditor"` yields 
  `drwxr-xr-x  5 albert albert   4096 Jan 22 10:22 ckeditor
  drwxr-xr-x  4 albert albert   4096 Jan 22 10:22 ckeditor_demo
  drwxr-xr-x  7 albert albert   4096 Jan 22 10:22 ckeditor_uploader
  drwxr-xr-x  2 albert albert   4096 Jan 22 10:22 django_ckeditor-5.8.0.dist-info`

  so it is in fact installed.
- `pip3 list` also shows `django-ckeditor 5.8.0`

So now I don't know where to go from here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the full error message for the `ModuleNotFoundError` Also check the output of adding `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` at the top of your script. The list should contain `.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

Comment: The full error message was just the django starting script. I've found the solution to my problem. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I was actually using a virtualenvironment that had my packages in `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. `ckeditor` was not there because I had used the "global" pip3.7 for that. The solution was to use `~/.local/bin/pip3.7 install django-ckeditor`.

Sorry for the confusion, nonetheless I hope to have helped someone with this issue in the future.